# How does couchdb indexer should work with reduce functions?

Tags: couchdb

I have a view where both map and reduce functions are defined and both reduced and non-reduced queries are useful in this view (non-reduced queries are most wanted here).

When it's reindexing small amount of 10k docs, CPU goes top and it takes ages to make full index. Removing (or simplifying) reduce function solves the problem, and in couchjs logs I can see, that reduce/rereduce calls consumes all resources.

The question is: why does couchdb calls reduce/rereduce to build index, even when view was queried with "reduce=false" option? I don't think it's possible use these values as precomputed, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do your map and reduce functions look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CouchDB Map/Reduce indexes are always fully precomputed and cached on disk; queries are satisfied from the on-disk index.

This means there are some constraints on what works well, in particular in reduce functions. The general idea is that your reduce function should emit values/structures that are constant in size. That means it's a bad idea if you have a reduce() function which accumulates data without actually reducing it (for example concatenating keys or values from the map phase into an array and then returning that array). In general, CouchDB comes configured with the `query_server_config.reduce_limit` option set to true to help prevent you from writing bad reduce functions.